# How to commuicate between cell phone applications?

Tags: android, networking, mobile

I am asking this here because I do not even know for sure how to phrase it to Google...

I want to know if there is some way for one cell phone application (say, Android, to restrict the scope) to communicate (or just send one way data) to the same application on another phone, possibly over the phone network.

What I want is a kind of SMS (or know if it is possible to use SMS for this purpose) that I send from an application in my cell phone with data that a peer application on a remote phone can understand, and the remote phone will know what application to use to handle that data.

Internet seems not the case here, because I want to identify the receiver of the message by phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for Google Cloud Messaging:

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

There are plenty of great examples on the site.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on something similar.  It looks like GCM could be a good option if you have relatively large packets of data to send.  I'm pursuing using SMS to send small amounts of polled or periodic data.  At least with Android, you can create a broadcast receiver to be notified of an SMS message (android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED) and you can abort the broadcast based on the sender, message data, etc thereby blocking the notification to the user about the SMS message.